# The variables that control glyph sizing in TrueType fonts

Tags: fonts, truetype, ttx-fonttools

I have the following data from ttx fonttools which describes a font binary I have built manually:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ttFont sfntVersion="true" ttLibVersion="3.36">

  <GlyphOrder>
    <!-- The 'id' attribute is only for humans; it is ignored when parsed. -->
    <GlyphID id="0" name=".notdef"/>
    <GlyphID id="1" name="b"/>
    <GlyphID id="2" name="d"/>
  </GlyphOrder>

  <head>
    <!-- Most of this table will be recalculated by the compiler -->
    <tableVersion value="1.0"/>
    <fontRevision value="1.0681"/>
    <checkSumAdjustment value="0x0"/>
    <magicNumber value="0x5f0f3cf5"/>
    <flags value="00000000 00000011"/>
    <unitsPerEm value="1000"/>
    <created value="Tue Jan 22 12:25:10 2019"/>
    <modified value="Tue Jan 22 12:25:10 2019"/>
    <xMin value="10"/>
    <yMin value="10"/>
    <xMax value="90"/>
    <yMax value="90"/>
    <macStyle value="00000000 00000000"/>
    <lowestRecPPEM value="3"/>
    <fontDirectionHint value="2"/>
    <indexToLocFormat value="1"/>
    <glyphDataFormat value="0"/>
  </head>

  <hhea>
    <tableVersion value="0x00010000"/>
    <ascent value="200"/>
    <descent value="100"/>
    <lineGap value="0"/>
    <advanceWidthMax value="90"/>
    <minLeftSideBearing value="0"/>
    <minRightSideBearing value="0"/>
    <xMaxExtent value="0"/>
    <caretSlopeRise value="1"/>
    <caretSlopeRun value="0"/>
    <caretOffset value="0"/>
    <reserved0 value="0"/>
    <reserved1 value="0"/>
    <reserved2 value="0"/>
    <reserved3 value="0"/>
    <metricDataFormat value="0"/>
    <numberOfHMetrics value="3"/>
  </hhea>

  <maxp>
    <!-- Most of this table will be recalculated by the compiler -->
    <tableVersion value="0x10000"/>
    <numGlyphs value="3"/>
    <maxPoints value="5"/>
    <maxContours value="1"/>
    <maxCompositePoints value="0"/>
    <maxCompositeContours value="0"/>
    <maxZones value="1"/>
    <maxTwilightPoints value="0"/>
    <maxStorage value="0"/>
    <maxFunctionDefs value="0"/>
    <maxInstructionDefs value="0"/>
    <maxStackElements value="0"/>
    <maxSizeOfInstructions value="0"/>
    <maxComponentElements value="0"/>
    <maxComponentDepth value="0"/>
  </maxp>

  <OS_2>
    <!-- The fields 'usFirstCharIndex' and 'usLastCharIndex'
         will be recalculated by the compiler -->
    <version value="5"/>
    <xAvgCharWidth value="90"/>
    <usWeightClass value="500"/>
    <usWidthClass value="5"/>
    <fsType value="00000000 00000000"/>
    <ySubscriptXSize value="650"/>
    <ySubscriptYSize value="699"/>
    <ySubscriptXOffset value="0"/>
    <ySubscriptYOffset value="140"/>
    <ySuperscriptXSize value="650"/>
    <ySuperscriptYSize value="699"/>
    <ySuperscriptXOffset value="0"/>
    <ySuperscriptYOffset value="479"/>
    <yStrikeoutSize value="49"/>
    <yStrikeoutPosition value="258"/>
    <sFamilyClass value="0"/>
    <panose>
      <bFamilyType value="0"/>
      <bSerifStyle value="0"/>
      <bWeight value="0"/>
      <bProportion value="0"/>
      <bContrast value="0"/>
      <bStrokeVariation value="0"/>
      <bArmStyle value="0"/>
      <bLetterForm value="0"/>
      <bMidline value="0"/>
      <bXHeight value="0"/>
    </panose>
    <ulUnicodeRange1 value="00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000"/>
    <ulUnicodeRange2 value="00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000"/>
    <ulUnicodeRange3 value="00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000"/>
    <ulUnicodeRange4 value="00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000"/>
    <achVendID value="XXXX"/>
    <fsSelection value="00000000 01000000"/>
    <usFirstCharIndex value="97"/>
    <usLastCharIndex value="100"/>
    <sTypoAscender value="200"/>
    <sTypoDescender value="100"/>
    <sTypoLineGap value="0"/>
    <usWinAscent value="90"/>
    <usWinDescent value="10"/>
    <ulCodePageRange1 value="00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001"/>
    <ulCodePageRange2 value="00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000"/>
    <sxHeight value="100"/>
    <sCapHeight value="40"/>
    <usDefaultChar value="0"/>
    <usBreakChar value="0"/>
    <usMaxContext value="0"/>
    <usLowerOpticalPointSize value="0.0"/>
    <usUpperOpticalPointSize value="0.15"/>
  </OS_2>

  <hmtx>
    <mtx name=".notdef" width="90" lsb="0"/>
    <mtx name="b" width="90" lsb="0"/>
    <mtx name="d" width="90" lsb="0"/>
  </hmtx>

  <cmap>
    <tableVersion version="0"/>
    <cmap_format_4 platformID="3" platEncID="1" language="0">
      <map code="0x62" name="b"/><!-- LATIN SMALL LETTER B -->
      <map code="0x64" name="d"/><!-- LATIN SMALL LETTER D -->
    </cmap_format_4>
  </cmap>

  <loca>
    <!-- The 'loca' table will be calculated by the compiler -->
  </loca>

  <glyf>

    <!-- The xMin, yMin, xMax and yMax values
         will be recalculated by the compiler. -->

    <TTGlyph name=".notdef" xMin="0" yMin="0" xMax="100" yMax="300">
      <contour>
        <pt x="10" y="10" on="1"/>
        <pt x="90" y="10" on="1"/>
        <pt x="90" y="90" on="1"/>
        <pt x="10" y="90" on="1"/>
        <pt x="10" y="10" on="1"/>
      </contour>
      <instructions/>
    </TTGlyph>

    <TTGlyph name="b" xMin="0" yMin="0" xMax="100" yMax="300">
      <contour>
        <pt x="10" y="10" on="1"/>
        <pt x="90" y="10" on="1"/>
        <pt x="90" y="90" on="1"/>
        <pt x="10" y="90" on="1"/>
        <pt x="10" y="10" on="1"/>
      </contour>
      <instructions/>
    </TTGlyph>

    <TTGlyph name="d" xMin="0" yMin="0" xMax="100" yMax="300">
      <contour>
        <pt x="10" y="10" on="1"/>
        <pt x="90" y="10" on="1"/>
        <pt x="90" y="90" on="1"/>
        <pt x="10" y="90" on="1"/>
        <pt x="10" y="10" on="1"/>
      </contour>
      <instructions/>
    </TTGlyph>

  </glyf>

  <name>
    <namerecord nameID="6" platformID="1" platEncID="0" langID="0x0" unicode="True">
      Foo
    </namerecord>
    <namerecord nameID="1" platformID="1" platEncID="0" langID="0x0" unicode="True">
      Foo
    </namerecord>
    <namerecord nameID="2" platformID="1" platEncID="0" langID="0x0" unicode="True">
      Regular
    </namerecord>
    <namerecord nameID="3" platformID="1" platEncID="0" langID="0x0" unicode="True">
      foo
    </namerecord>
    <namerecord nameID="4" platformID="1" platEncID="0" langID="0x0" unicode="True">
      Foo Regular
    </namerecord>
    <namerecord nameID="13" platformID="1" platEncID="0" langID="0x0" unicode="True">
      Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    </namerecord>
    <namerecord nameID="5" platformID="1" platEncID="0" langID="0x0" unicode="True">
      Version 1.000
    </namerecord>
  </name>

  <post>
    <formatType value="3.0"/>
    <italicAngle value="0.0"/>
    <underlinePosition value="0"/>
    <underlineThickness value="0"/>
    <isFixedPitch value="0"/>
    <minMemType42 value="0"/>
    <maxMemType42 value="0"/>
    <minMemType1 value="0"/>
    <maxMemType1 value="0"/>
  </post>

</ttFont>
```

All 3 symbols are just a square:

```
<TTGlyph name="d" xMin="0" yMin="0" xMax="100" yMax="300">
  <contour>
    <pt x="10" y="10" on="1"/>
    <pt x="90" y="10" on="1"/>
    <pt x="90" y="90" on="1"/>
    <pt x="10" y="90" on="1"/>
    <pt x="10" y="10" on="1"/>
  </contour>
  <instructions/>
</TTGlyph>
```

What it shows up for me in the Font viewer is this:

[image]

Just some diagonal lines at the bottom corner.

In the browser when the letters `b` and `d` are styled with the font, it shows up with pretty much no width or probably height either. It looks like it's a tiny square though.

[image]

Wondering what I'm missing. Specifically, the following are the variables involved in the actual display/sizing/positioning of the glyphs.

- `glyf` table:

  - numberOfContours
  - xMin
  - yMin
  - xMax
  - yMax
  - endPtsOfContours
  - instructionLength
  - flags
  - xCoordinates
  - yCoordinates
- `head` table:

  - unitsPerEm
  - xMin
  - yMin
  - xMax
  - yMax
  - lowestRecPPEM
- `hhea` table:

  - ascender
  - descender
  - advanceWidthMax
  - minLeftSideBearing
  - minRightSideBearing
  - xMaxExtent: maxLeftSideBearing + (xMax - xMin),
- `os2` table: I think this isn't necessary, not sure though, but there's a few variables related to size/positioning here that are duplicates of others in other tables.
- `post` table:

  - isFixedPitch (monospaced fonts)

I think that's pretty much it. Please let me know if there is any *required* more than this.

These properties *somehow* control the size/position of the glyph. I think the glyph display problem above might have something to do with the size/scale of these variables. I'm not sure if they should be on the *order-of-magnitude* of 100, of 1000, or 10,000, etc. I'm not sure what is the "anchor" size that everything is based off. Maybe it's `unitsPerEm`, or maybe it's based on the `xMin` and `xMax` and `yMin` and `yMax` (so 100, 300).

What I currently have for these values are this:

- `glyf` table:

  - numberOfContours: 1
  - xMin: 0
  - yMin: 0
  - xMax: 100
  - yMax: 300
  - endPtsOfContours: lastIndex
  - instructionLength: 0
  - flags: flags
  - xCoordinates: relativeCoordinates
  - yCoordinates: relativeCoordinates
- `head` table:

  - unitsPerEm: 2000
  - xMin: 0
  - yMin: 0
  - xMax: 100
  - yMax: 300
  - lowestRecPPEM: 3
- `hhea` table:

  - ascender: 200
  - descender: -100 (but it always becomes 100, so maybe - isn't necessary)
  - advanceWidthMax: glyphs[i].advanceWidth max
  - minLeftSideBearing: 0
  - minRightSideBearing: 100
  - xMaxExtent: maxLeftSideBearing + (xMax - xMin),
- `os2` table: I think this isn't necessary, not sure though, but there's a few variables related to size/positioning here that are duplicates of others in other tables.
- `post` table:

  - isFixedPitch true (since it's simpler for now)

My questions are:

1. What these values should be (in the list above).
2. What the "anchor" value is, where everything is relative to that scale/size (if one exists).
3. How I go about placing a glyph into a bounding box so that it appears flush with whatever other font there is on the screen (or at least it's relatively close to the same size). In my font I only have characters `b` and `d`, so if I write `abcd` I should see `a□c□` if my character is just drawing a simple square for each (and the sizing should be about the same). Right now I just see a small diagonal line.